# how dynamically i can checked and unchecked radio button on the basis of list of values returned by controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing a edit functionality. Initially user has selected a list of radio buttons while create functionality i have stored them in a table as CSV as string. Now in edit functionality i am getting this list as a string of csv but i am facing difficulty to make radio buttons checked which are in string of csv dynamically.

case1

```
user has selected 4 radio button out of 10 radio buttons. I have passed this list to controller and saved in a table as String of csv.
```

case 2

```
 In edit function in controller i am getting a string var like this 
  String radiolist=radio1,radio2,radio3,radio4
```

Now i am redirecting to a edit jps page where i want only these 4 radio should get checked rest should be unchecked. can any one help to do this?

Comment: Do you have a common class added to radio buttons?

Comment: use serialize array and put your radio button in form

Answer (score 1):

You can use [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method:

```
$(':radio').serializeArray(); // a name attribute must be set on each radio button
```

If you want to get an array containing the value for each checked radio button, you can use:

```
var arrValuesRD = $(':radio:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value; // default is 'on' if no value attribute is set
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
var val=$("input:radio[name='police']:checked").val();
radioValueArray.push(val);
```

do same for each name group and push.